# Building Login onto already existing app

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, authentication

I am building a login onto an completed app. The app have already used the appdelegate but in order to do the login, it needs to use the appdelegate. I am stuck at a point where I cannot "make a new reference outlet for your Navigation Controller to your App Delegate." since the appdelegate in not in my .xib.

How can I make the appdelegate appear on the .xib file so I can link it with the navigation controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to first understand the architecture of your app. But even without that, one solution that I could think of is this.

Create a viewController named ValidateViewController by right clicking on your project-> add new file -> UIViewControllerSubClass and check the xib option as well.

This will generate the following

ValidateViewController.h

ValidateViewController.m

ValidateViewController.xib

Write all your validations functions in this class. Write a function in this class that would return true on validation success and false on validation failure. Now let's use this class in your appdelegate.

Now in your appdelegate.h, import this ValidateViewController.h. All the validation functions that you defined in the ValidateViewController will now be exposed to be used just by creating and allocating an object of ValidateViewController in your appdelegate. I hope this is pretty straight forward for you. If not, we can look at it again.

Now in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method of your appdelegate, the first thing you do is you load this ValidateViewController  as a modalView controller programmatically. Once loaded, call the functions and get the return values from your validate functions, if validation succeeds, dismiss this modalViewController otherwise, you pop up an alertView in the modalViewController saying, validation was unsuccessful and the user stays on the ValidationViewController. I think that should solve your problem. If you need more help please come back. If you find the answer satisfactory, please accept it.

Comment: OK. I have read something about this. So you think I should have the login as a modal view which would just go onto of the app? As my app has tabbarcontrollers etc, would that conflict as I have seen many people that cannot load the tabbarcontroller after log in. In your last paragraph, you told me about the applicationDidFinishing method. What kind of code would I need to put as I am unsure. Thank you so much.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working but what I have done is load the modalview on the viewdidload of my first view. But when I run the app, I will see the app then the modalview slides up to cover it. I did type the correct creditials which gives me access to the app. Does that matter?

Comment: Hi, it's advisable that you do it in your applicationDidFinishLaunchMethod. Let me take a look at your code and I will fix it for you. It should be an easy fix. Send me your app delegate code and may be a couple of screenshots.

Comment: Hey, Try this: http://img683.imageshack.us/i/unlediem.png/ and http://img691.imageshack.us/i/unled1hl.png/ Thanks.